# About instructor's manual in math textbooks: principles, design, uses and impact

Tags: reference-request, textbooks

It is common that school math textbooks are supplemented with instructor's materials (answers, hints and guidelines).
Are there scientific studies on how instructor's materials impact math teaching?
Any reference about the world of instructor's material (design, principles, uses, etc.) are welcome.

Comment: I don't know of any (but I don't know much of math education literature), although I would be surprised if this were not something that has been academically studied several times. That said, it's worth mentioning that the stimulus for such materials is almost entirely a financial decision for the publisher and is not really motivated by its impact on math teaching, although the individual writers of such material, often being teachers or former teachers, probably keep its impact in mind for personal altruistic reasons.

Comment: It'd be my impression that nowadays it's mostly publishers who insist on such things... and students who want to covertly acquire them. Serious instructors know not to entirely trust such material, in the first place, but/and also don't really need to look at it, anyway. So I'd anticipate that an answer to the question, as posed, would be misleading, due to built-in assumptions. But ... I don't know...

Answer (score 1):

some research on the topic:

1. LCROSS-CULTURAL ANALYSIS OF THE VOICE OF
   CURRICULUM MATERIALS by Janine Remillard, Hendrik Van Steenbrugge, Tomas Bergqvist

[International Conference on
Mathematics Textbook Research and Development 2014](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjQ48DI8Y_8AhXwD7kGHcQhC74QFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.diva-portal.org%2Fsmash%2Fget%2Fdiva2%3A805729%2FFULLTEXT03.pdf&usg=AOvVaw06yFQA3IAWnD1xtFZfdCUa)

2. Textbooks and Teachers' Guides: A Dilemma for Beginning Teachers and Teacher
   Educators by Deborah Loewenberg Ball and Sharon Feiman-NemserSource[JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1179386?origin=JSTOR-pdf)
3. TEACHER MANUAL OF SCHOOL-BASED AND CLASSROOM-BASED ACTIVITIES TO SUPPORT ALL LEARNERS BY Judith Hollenweger AND Edina Krompák
   [UNICEF](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiHs-7Jh5D8AhXOHbkGHQFQAlIQFnoECAoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.unicef.org%2Fnorthmacedonia%2Freports%2Fteacher-manual-school-based-and-classroom-based-activities-support-all-learners&usg=AOvVaw2xPMenP7jzWmz48xhuuOtc)
4. Design Principles for Learning to Guide Teacher Walk
   Throughs BY Eric Feeney. [Journal of Educational Strategies, Issues and Ideas](http://www.tandfonline.com/action/showCitFormats?doi=10.1080/00098655.2013.823903).

the world of teacher's manual and guides for textbooks needes more research!